# How to blur an image from command line?

Tags: command-line, imagemagick, image-editor

I know it is possible to convert from png to jpg in command line with imagemagick. Is it possible to blur from commandline too?

I have found [this documentation](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#gaussian-blur) but it does not demonstrate how this could be done from the command line.

Answer (score 14):

generalizing from [an answer answer from this forum](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2195799):

```
convert orig_file.jpg -blur 0x8 blured_file.jpg
```

or

```
convert orig_file.jpg -filter Gaussian -blur 0x8 blured_file.jpg
```

where `0x8` defines `radiusxsigma` from the imagemagick documentation:

> The Sigma value is the important argument, and determines the actual amount of blurring that will take place.
>
> The Radius is only used to determine the size of the array which will hold the calculated Gaussian distribution. It should be an integer. If not given, or set to zero, IM will calculate the largest possible radius that will provide meaningful results for the Gaussian distribution.
>
> The larger the Radius the radius the slower the operation is. However too small a Radius, and severe aliasing effects may result. As a guideline, Radius should be at least twice the Sigma value, though three times will produce a more accurate result.

Comment: The quote seems to contradicts the command given, as the radius in `0x8` is less than twice of sigma. But when the radius value is `0`, `convert` will calculate an ideal radius itself